# Algorithms additions

Tags: algorithm

For the  algorithms below I need help with the following.

1. ```
   Algorithm Sum(m, n) 
   //Input: A positive integer n and another positive integer m ≤ n 
   //Output: ? 
   sum = 0 
   for i=m to n do 
   for j=1 to i do 
   sum = sum + 1 
   end for j 
   end for i 
   return sum
   ```

   I need help figuring out what it computes? And what is the formula of the total number of additions sum=(sum+1).

   I have The algorithm computes all of the positive integers between m and n including m and n.
   The formula for the number of additions is.
   m+m+1+…..+n

Comment: Take a pencil and paper and pretend you are the computer, work through a few examples with small values for `m` and `n`.

Comment: Is this a homework problem? Just pick n = 12 and m=10. Or n=6 and m=6. Do the math as HP Mark suggests and write down all your steps. The output is going to be a single number, but you can write it as a sum of specific integers. I'll let you determine for yourself what those integers are.

Comment: Okay here's what I want to add after you edited the question...
If you want the complexity analysis, I have answered it below;
If you want to see what it outputs, basically you can just code these two for loops out, plug some n,m values and try it by yourself...

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your questions...It seems you ask something but you also provide the answers by yourself already...anyway here's my answer to the questions...

For Q1, it seems you are asking the output and the number of total number of iteration (which is `summation(m..n) =  (n+m)(n-m+1)/2`)

For Q2, it seems you are also asking how many times of the comparison has been performed, which is `n-1` times.

To solve the recurrence T(n) = aT(n-1) + c where a,c is a constant, 
by repeat substitution of `n-2`, `n-3` ... until 1, you can find that `T(n) = O(n)`

**PS**: If it is a homework, maybe you did as you seem to have your own answer already, I strongly advice you to try go through some specific cases For Q1. For Q2 you should try to understand several methods to work out the recurrence relation, substitution method can be used to solve this kind of easy relation,  many others may need to use [master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem).

Also you should be make yourself able to understand why Q2's complexity is actually the same as a normal naive for loop iterative method.